# Remove escape sequence from string in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I'm facing an issue with removing escape sequence from string using C#

```
var street = "1324 W. 650 N.\t";
```

Above I mentioned my code please check once and mention below comments on how to remove escape sequences like "\t".

Comment: The variable `street`'s value contains a tab character not an escape sequence, what do you want to do with it?

Comment: There's nothing specific to C# 4, or ASP.NET-MVC or ASP.NET-Core in your question. Please only use tags that are specifically relevant to the question.

Comment: Do you want to remove escape sequences or trim whitespace? For example, what result would you want for `var street = "   1234 \x57. M\u00FCller St.\t";`?

Comment: Alex K I want to remove the tab character.

Comment: Jon Skeet Okay noted.

Comment: Dour High Arch I just want to remove the tab character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to remove '\t' try:

```
var street = "1324 W. 650 N.\t";
var removed = street.Replace("\t", "");
```

In case you would also like to remove '\n' and '\r' too, you can concatenate the operation '`Replace()`'.

```
var street = "1324 W. 650 N.\t";
var removed = street.Replace("\t", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
```

Check the [example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7xU4mg) I made.

Comment: Yes I tried this, is there any other way to handle  this  Beer Baron

Comment: But it doesn't work for you or you just want another way? I can check it with Regular Expressions.

Comment: Yes its working for me but I need another way!

Comment: Check this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7xU4mg). Is like the other way but with regex.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use Regex.Unescape method.

```
String unescapedString = Regex.Unescape(textString);
```

However, becareful that the [Regex.Unescape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.unescape?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Unescape_System_String_) doesn't un-escape ". According to the documentation, it does the following:

..by removing the escape character ("") from each character escaped by the method. These include the , *, +, ?, |, {, [, (,), ^, $,., #, and white space characters. In addition, the Unescape method unescapes the closing bracket (]) and closing brace (}) characters.